# Nested ES6 promises - outer func error not caught

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm new to ES6 & a series of promises. My situation is that the original call site calls a function (1), which then calls another function (2). Attempting to have both function 2 & function 1 return a promise based on success or error.

Here is some sample, contrived code:

```
function level2(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('fail')
  })
}

function level1(info) {
  level2('abc').then((response) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('success')
    })
  })
}

level1('thing').then((response) => {
  console.log('response2 ' + response)
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('error2 ' + e)
})
```

I'm able to use one level of promises successfully. But when it comes to chaining or nesting promises, I'm not using it properly, so the outermost layer that consumes the promise is not catching the error.

What is the correct way to setup promises so that both functions (level 1 & 2) can return success or failure to the caller?

In the example function (level1), would the error from function (level2) get bubbled outwards?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get `level1` to return a promise.

```js
{
  // level2 reject:
  function level2(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject('fail inside level2')
    })
  }

  function level1(info) {
    return level2('abc').then((response) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('success')
      })
    })
  }

  level1('thing').then((response) => {
    console.log('response2 ' + response)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log('error2 ' + e)
  });
}

{
  // level1 reject:
  function level2(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('ok');
    })
  }

  function level1(info) {
    return level2('abc').then((response) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('fail inside level1')
      })
    })
  }

  level1('thing').then((response) => {
    console.log('response2 ' + response)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log('error2 ' + e)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you dont need these:

```
 new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  reject('fail'))
```

There are shortcuts for it:

```
 Promise.resolve("success")
 Promise.reject("fail");
```

> What is the correct way to setup promises so that both functions (level 1 & 2) can return success or failure to the caller?

Either use `Promise.all` or `Promise.race` to unify them or return one of the promises into the then chain of the other one, so that they get flattened (just as you did).

> In the example function (level1), would the error from function (level2) get bubbled outwards?

Yes.

Comment: can you provide an example of `Promise.all`? 

In my situation, I kind of want to keep the knowledge of the 2nd promise hidden from the original caller, if the original caller doesn't need to know about the nested promise, then they shouldn't

Comment: @xta jup, in your case your solution is right. But there are some other cases were Promise.all achieves a similar purpose.